# Singapore Visa for business meetings local contact

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, business-travel

- I am currently working in the UK
- I have an Indian Passport
- I have to visit the Singapore branch to attend a few meetings
- I have a completed 14A
- I have a completed V39A from the company
- Hotel, and travel fully booked.

My question is -

Can I get a Singapore local working in the office to submit the application via SAVE?

The wording on the website makes it look as if this is only an option for a tourist visa.

Do I need to use a travel agent in the UK to process this?

Sahil.

Comment: Are you referring to https://eservices.ica.gov.sg/esvclandingpage/save? What did your Singapore office say about submitting on your behalf when you asked them?

Comment: Exactly! So I asked the office about this . Unfortunately, nobody at the firm who has had to travel comes from a country needing a visa, so they aren't sure of the process. I absolutely do not mind a 'authorized agent' but the embassy website in the UK doesn't publish a list and I'm weary of getting scammed.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you apply for a visa directly from the Singapore High Commission in London https://www.mfa.gov.sg/Overseas-Mission/London/Important-Information/Visa-Information the High Commission is the equivalent of an embassy (the term is used for ex-UK colonies I believe).

Comment: Actually, that page ends with “_ Note: Your visa application can also be submitted online using the e-service SAVE through a local contact in Singapore (must be a Singapore Citizen or a Singapore PR who is at least 21 years old with a SingPass account/CorpPass account)_”

Comment: I would have, but they have 0 appointments in Nov.

Comment: Company isn't familiar with Corp pass application, so my SG MD counterpart is fine with doing it himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use the [e-Service](https://eservices.ica.gov.sg/esvclandingpage/save) for business trips, and in fact I did just this for a colleague who needed to visit Singapore last month.  It was issued in under 48 hours, making this much faster and more convenient than the embassy application route, particularly since you don't need to wait for an appointment.

There are actually two options: the *company* can sponsor the visa via CorpPass ([guide PDF](https://www.ica.gov.sg/docs/default-source/ica/files/gc_usermanual_ip_save_corppass.pdf?sfvrsn=abca7037_10)), or an *individual* working at the company can sponsor it ([guide PDF](https://www.ica.gov.sg/docs/default-source/ica/files/gc_usermanual_ip_save_singpass.pdf?sfvrsn=e05edc6a_8)).  I would recommend the corporate path if your company is flexible enough to handle it, but somebody with CorpPass logins has to do it and typically this access is limited to HR/accounting.  We ended up getting an individual to do it, and this too was fine.